# Issue in row updating in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I am using a grid view with auto generate column =true;
When I am updating the grid

```
  protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    { 
     TextBox tPropertyId  = (TextBox)row.FindControl("PropertyId");
    }
```

is getting called.The proplem is thaT , `tPropertyId` is getting null value and when I am doing 
    `tPropertyId.Text` , I am getting null reference exception.

Please Help.

Comment: What's `row`? Have a look at the [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Footer) return;
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```